# Is there any local history in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ide, visual-studio-extensions

That is a really useful feature, there are many IDEs that can provide it but I can't find any extension which can provide Local History.

By Local History I mean something that tracks any changes and edits that I make on the source code so I can be able to recover it in future.

Comment: Do I must put my source code on Internet ? Or can I use Team Foundation without internet ? It is a local history, or a server based history ?

Comment: No.  http://try.github.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is a source code control system.  Visual Studio does not provide this by default as its primary job is that of an editor.  It does support a number of source code control plugins, many for free, which will do this for you.

For example there is a free `Git` plugin that is now officially provided by Microsoft.

> http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c

This can be used with a number of free Git providers

- [CodePlex](http://codeplex.com)
- [GitHub](http://github.com)
- [Visual Studio Hosting](https://visualstudio.com/)

Comment: And it's worth mentioning, if having code "on the internet" scares you, Git can do all it's management locally without you ever pushing it to any other machine, if you wish.

Comment: Thank you for these answers.

Answer (score 9):

There is a separate extension that provides local history functionality:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/226c2108-9da9-407d-b90d-9783040d27b8

I think the local history feature complements version control.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to have best of both worlds:

[autogit - Visual Studio extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/45a3d62b-955e-43cb-9d91-255a837d5f35)

Here are some counter reasons why local history is different then source code repository:

Some simple reasons:

- simple insurance against accidental changes or deletions.
- makes it easier to support smarter undo, backtracking, or exploratory programming.
- resume a task or track a task by seeing changes at a fine-grain level as they happened.
- light-weight, stays invisible until you need it.

Some deeper reasons:

- **Better Task Resumption:** research suggests that resuming an interrupted task or reviewing a change made by another is made easier when changes can be reviewed in an time-ordered manner (in comparision to a flat commit).
- **Auto-blog:** [automark](https://github.com/chrisparnin/automark) is a sister project that can examine a git repository and then automatically generate a markdown file, in a format suitable for publishing a blog post.
- **Personal Analytics:** Watts Humphrey has advocated the idea of tracking personal activity for self-improvement, using methods such as the Personal Software Process.  Using services, such as [codealike](http://codealike.com/) or [codeivate](http://www.codeivate.com/), you can track things like time spent editing, etc.  Tracking the *actual* changes can take this analysis to another level.
- **Api Analytics:** Frequent mistakes are made when programming or using particular apis.  This can be analyzed: "You spent 3 hours figuring out how to correctly use pygit2.create_commit(), create github issue?"

Answer (score 1):

There's also the Auto History Extension: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dfcb2438-180c-4f8a-983b-62d89e141fe3

It's like the one Juha Palomäki linked to, except has more downloads, reviews, and a slightly higher average-review. (haven't tried either myself yet, though plan to in a day or two)